# Use entire set of views in two different URL confs in Django

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm building a web app that displays TV `Shows` and `Episodes`. All my urls are geared towards TV Shows being the top level concept:

- mysite.com/tv-show-name/episode-name
- mysite.com/tv-show-name/episode-name/cast
- mysite.com/tv-show-name/episode-name/reviews

I've gotten interest from `Networks` for consolidated pages with their shows as subdirectories

- mysite.com/network-name/tv-show-name/episode-name
- mysite.com/network-name/tv-show-name/episode-name/cast
- mysite.com/network-name/tv-show-name/episode-name/reviews

I'll need to support both, and obviously I dont want to repeat all my non-network URL confs. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: So the desired outcome is that both urls point to the same page basically or that the `networks` urls overwrite the `non-Network` ones so to say?

Comment: Yes. mysite.com/tv-show-1 and mysite.com/network/tv-show-1 both load the same view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include the same url patterns more than once. In your case, you can include them with and without the network name prefix

```
from django.urls import path, include

episode_patterns = [
    path('<str:tv_show_name>/<str:episode_name>/', episode_detail),
    path('<str:tv_show_name>/<str:episode_name>/cast/', episode_cast),
    path('<str:tv_show_name>/<str:episode_name>/reviews/', episode_reviews),
]

urlpatterns = [
    path('<str:network_name>/', include(episode_patterns)),
    path('', include(episode_patterns)),
]
```

You may want to think about including "prefixes" in your paths so that they are more explicit. As it stands it could be fairly confusing as to which url is being matched

```
from django.urls import path, include

episode_patterns = [
    path('show/<str:tv_show_name>/episode/<str:episode_name>/', episode_detail),
    path('show/<str:tv_show_name>/episode/<str:episode_name>/cast/', episode_cast),
    path('show/<str:tv_show_name>/episode/<str:episode_name>/reviews/', episode_reviews),
]

urlpatterns = [
    path('network/<str:network_name>/', include(episode_patterns)),
    path('', include(episode_patterns)),
]
```

This would give you urls like

- mysite.com/show/tv-show-name/episode/episode-name/
- mysite.com/network/network-name/show/tv-show-name/episode/episode-name/

Comment: Question on this. Would I then need to add a if kwargs['network_name'] lookup to every view?

Comment: @Brenden Yes you would, if you are using class based views you may be able to use some kind of baseclass/mixin to handle it

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through your `urlpatterns` list again after definition.

Then `str.replace()` for the url and append to the existing list?

For keyword `name=<your_url_name>` in url to remain unique, Add a prefix to separate network from tv.

Comment: @Brenden What do you mean?

Comment: I think you're getting at what @Iain Shelvington did above. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, that's it! No problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<tv-show-name>', render_your_view, name='tv-show'),
    path('<network-name>/<tv-show-name>', render_your_view, name='network'),
]
```

So no matter if the requested URL is on a tv-show level or network-level, it triggers the according view(s).

Comment: I dont want to have to copy every show URL pattern (there are many). Seems very error prone